# Why is my query only grabbing 3 items instead of the intended amount?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query.

```
$request = "SELECT
            required_items.id,
            required_items.name,
            required_items.required_amount AS Amount_Required,
            COALESCE(SUM(donations.donation_amount),0) AS Amount_Donated
            FROM required_items 
LEFT JOIN donations ON donations.item_id=required_items.id 
GROUP BY item_id ASC";

$stmt = $db->query($request);
$item_info = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I am only receiving three of the five items in my "required_items" database. I intend for this to fetch all of them. What can I be doing wrong? I'm stumped.

Upon further testing I noticed the items are not being grouped with"item_id" in ascending order.

EDIT:
Here's my fiddle for this problem:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7afc3/1/0

The intended results would be to list all five items in the database in the manner they are displayed with the query, instead of just three.

EDIT: I was grouping by a column in the wrong table! "item_id" needed to be changed to "required_items.id".

Comment: Are you sure your query returns more the 3 items? Did you test it on the database?

Comment: When I run this query directly into the database via phpmyadmin I'm only receiving three items, so it must not be any of my other code.

Comment: Could it be the GROUP BY clause is causing the problems?

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I remove the GROUP BY clause, I only receive the first entry in my database...Something is wrong here. I'm not well versed in maintaining databases.

Comment: Build your schema on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and share a link. Update your question with what's the expected result.

Comment: @user2766423, you have an aggregate query (on account of the use of the `SUM()` function in the select list).  It will return one row for each distinct combination of values of the `GROUP BY` columns.  If there is no `GROUP BY` clause then there are zero grouping columns, and thus everything is aggregated into the same group.

Comment: About your edit, I think you need `ORDER BY item_id ASC`

Comment: @user2766423, do please present the schema and [sample] data for your tables, and the results you want your query to return for those data.

Comment: @Berriel I tried that and only received the first entry in the database. I've updated the post with a fiddle.

Comment: Could it be you're not grouping by prmaries/unique IDS rather than duplicate keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grouping on a table that has only 3 rows selected (two with values and one null), you could use the field from the other table:

```
$request = "SELECT
            required_items.id,
            required_items.name,
            required_items.required_amount AS Amount_Required,
            COALESCE(SUM(donations.donation_amount),0) AS Amount_Donated
            FROM required_items 
LEFT JOIN donations ON donations.item_id=required_items.id 
GROUP BY required_items.id ASC"; // <- MODIFIED HERE

$stmt = $db->query($request);
$item_info = $stmt->fetchAll();
```